# Disable "most recently used items" for Business Process Flow lookups

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-365-v9

We are using Account to store multiple account-types: vendor, a distributor, a supplier, a partner. In some scenarios we only want to allow an operator to select a 'vendor' Account which we've achieved by setting a lookup filter.

However, the recently used items list seems to bypass this filter and just show all Accounts regardless of type, so we need to disable it via the below options

[image: Options]

These options only apply to that instance of the control. When the same field is included in a Business Process Flow, the recent items appear again.

How can we replicate this behaviour for lookups in a Business Process Flow?

I don't mind if this is done via JavaScript, as long as it uses supported methods. I haven't been able to spot the correct property here [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/reference/controls#lookup-control-type)

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to add the same lookup attribute in another form section, set the property “Disable most recently used items for this field” by checking the checkbox in form control. This will replicate the setting to BPF field also.

Later you can remove the field from form section & the setting persists in BPF field.

[Disable Recent Records in Business Process Flow](https://community.dynamics.com/365/sales/f/762/t/312841)